# Why does postfix main.cf contain configuration like readme_directory, manpage_directory etc?

Tags: configuration, postfix

I am setting up a mailserver with Postfix. While configuring it, I see the following values in main.cf. What causes these entries to appear?

```
   manpage_directory       = /usr/share/man
   sample_directory        = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
   readme_directory        = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
```

I looked it up and this is in the manpage.

> readme_directory (default: see "postconf -d" output)
>
> The location of
> Postfix README files that describe how to build, configure or operate
> a specific Postfix subsystem or feature.

Comment: ... Anyways I dived into the postfix src and found out why, but because I cannot answer this question except this comment. I will just say it belongs to legacy code.

Comment: It's reopened, you can answer it now